# Tmp script file not found - Airflow - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, airflow-scheduler, airflow

One of the task is failed due to `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`. Below are parts of log that might be helpful.

```
[2020-10-17 21:15:59,086] {bash_operator.py:113} INFO - Tmp dir root location: 
/tmp
[2020-10-17 21:15:59,090] {bash_operator.py:136} INFO - Temporary script location: 
/tmp/airflowtmpf1umw2qp/task_ugp_ugo_ux_east_eop_vldkgwtbl2z
```

...

```
[2020-10-20 06:18:03,803] {bash_operator.py:161} INFO - Command exited with return code 0
[2020-10-20 06:18:03,805] {taskinstance.py:1150} ERROR - [Errno 2] No such file or 
directory: '/tmp/airflowtmpf1umw2qp/task_ugp_ugo_ux_east_eop_vldkgwtbl2z'

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/airflow/etl/pyenv/pyugp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", 
line 984, in _run_raw_task
result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
File "/airflow/etl/pyenv/pyugp/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/airflow/operators/bash_operator.py", line 165, in execute
raise AirflowException("Bash command failed")
File "/airflow/etl/software/python37/lib/python3.7/tempfile.py", line 500, in __exit__
self.close()
File "/airflow/etl/software/python37/lib/python3.7/tempfile.py", line 507, in close
self._closer.close()
File "/airflow/etl/software/python37/lib/python3.7/tempfile.py", line 444, in close
unlink(self.name)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'/tmp/airflowtmpf1umw2qp/task_ugp_ugo_ux_east_eop_vldkgwtbl2z'
```

As it is shown in the log, the Temporary script was created on 17-10-2020 and the error was thrown on 20-10-2020, during this period it was waiting for a `cfg` and a `data` file which will be used for validation.